# Multiple alter column statements in a single alter table statement causes 'row length exceeded limit'

Tags: db2, ddl, alter-table

I use DB2 in version 9.7.0.2.

I have a table created with the following DDL:

```
  CREATE TABLE atable (
     id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     int1 int NOT NULL,
     int2 int NOT NULL,
     smallint1 smallint NOT NULL,

     dec1 decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
     dec2 decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
     dec3 decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
     dec4 decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
     dec5 decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
     dec6 decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
     dec7 decimal (11,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
     dec8 decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
  );

  CREATE INDEX i_atable_int1 ON atable(int1);
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pk_atable ON atable(id);
```

I want to enlarge length of all the decimal columns. So I run an `alter table` statement as follows:

```
    ALTER TABLE atable
        ALTER COLUMN dec1 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4)
        ALTER COLUMN dec2 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4)
        ALTER COLUMN dec3 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4)
        ALTER COLUMN dec4 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4)
        ALTER COLUMN dec5 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4)
        ALTER COLUMN dec6 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4)
        ALTER COLUMN dec7 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4)
        ALTER COLUMN dec8 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4);
```

Which causes: `The row length of the table exceeded a limit of "4005" bytes. (Table space "USERSPACE1".). SQLCODE=-670, SQLSTATE=54010, DRIVER=3.59.81 SQL Code: -670, SQL State: 54010`

The statement doesn't fail when the table is created in a tablespace with 16k page size, but please keep in mind that the row length calculated by hand is far, far away from 4005 bytes.

Also things are getting strange when I split the statement into multiple `alter table`'s:

```
    ALTER TABLE atable
        ALTER COLUMN dec1 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4);
    ALTER TABLE atable
        ALTER COLUMN dec2 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4);
    ALTER TABLE atable
        ALTER COLUMN dec3 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4);
    ALTER TABLE atable   
        ALTER COLUMN dec4 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4);
    ALTER TABLE atable
        ALTER COLUMN dec5 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4);
    ALTER TABLE atable
        ALTER COLUMN dec6 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4);
    ALTER TABLE atable
        ALTER COLUMN dec7 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4);
    ALTER TABLE atable
        ALTER COLUMN dec8 SET DATA TYPE decimal(23, 4);
```

All statements run and the columns are enlarged.

What can be the reason of this surprising behaviour?

Comment: Check your script, I run it, and I got: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pk_atable ON atable(id)
SQL0605W  The index was not created because an index
"SYSIBM.SQL130507163010350" with a matching definition already exists.
SQLSTATE=01550

Comment: BTW, the rest worked for me in v9.7.4 64 bits.

Comment: The whole script runs on my version. @AngocA could you execute the one-line alter the second time? I can execute it just after the creation of the table, but I can't execute it the second time.